# Is there a limit to Gmail filter-criteria Query size/length?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, quota

I want to add newsletter/mailing list emails to a filter and attach an action to it.
The filter criteria query size could go up to 100s of emails (format: {from:email1 from:email2 ...})

So I want to know if there's a character limit to the criteria query.

---

I found an answer on StackExchange (3 years old) it says 1500 character limit but I don't see that number anywhere on gmail-api docs or any other place.

[https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-items-a-filter-can-search-for-in-gmail#:~:text=Yes%3A%201%2C500%20characters.,shouldn't%20get%20performance%20issues](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-items-a-filter-can-search-for-in-gmail#:%7E:text=Yes%3A%201%2C500%20characters.,shouldn%27t%20get%20performance%20issues).